# CNAME, bluehost and github.io

Tags: dns

I'm trying to set a custom domain, provided by bluehost, for my github.io page.  I managed to get it working for www.mydomain.com but not mydomain.com.  So, if the address is listed as just mydomain.com, it directs to a generic bluehost page.

Here's what I did.

1. On github.io, under settings, I listed the custom domain as www.mydomain.com.
2. On bluehost, under 'CNAME' settings, I listed 'host record': www 'points to': githubname.github.io.
3. On bluehost, under 'CNAME' settings, I listed 'host record': mydomain 'points to': www

But, this doesn't seem to do it. Steps 1 and 2 seem to work, but not step 3.

Bluehost is not all that happy supporting this, because they want me to pay for hosting, so I haven't found much help here.

There are some posts about similar issues, but I can't tell if this is just something that my DNS doesn't support, or if there is a workaround.  Lots of the posts I am seeing here are when people can directly edit their cname file.

Thanks so much!

SOLVED:
1. edit the Aname 'host record' @ to point to the ip-address of your github.io site.
2. To find your github.io ip-address ping it in the terminal.

Then do the same steps 1 and 2 as above.

Comment: Hey!! I'm trying to set up bluehost domain on pages too. I followed your steps (1 & 2 and then the Solved section) but it isn't working for me. I'm getting a 404 error when I enter the domain. can you help me out at all please? I'm incredibly new to hosting / domain names :)

Comment: Step 1 should actually just be mydomain.com when used with the solution